# button - onclick - request to go direct to link doesn't work

Tags: html, css, onclick

section that isn't working - i've tried a couple different methods but can't get it to go.

```
<div class="dropdown">
          <div style="height:51px;" onclick="parent.location='default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=3'">
          <button class="dropbtn"><font color="#FFFFFF">HEADWEAR</font></button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In its current state, this question is quite hard to answer. To increase the changes of getting it answered you could add more information, such as what you want to happen and more information about what is actually happening, as well as any debugging information you have gathered.

Comment: when clicking the above it goes to the url:  default.aspx?p=search

Comment: I'm looking for it to go to:  default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=3

Comment: You should use window.location.href on click and it should be used on button as button have a click even.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the onclick that it is using `javascript:` so the entire onclick line is:
`onclick="javascript:document.location.href='default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=3'"`

full example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div style="height:51px;" onclick="javascript:document.location.href='default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=3'">
          <button class="dropbtn"><font color="#FFFFFF">HEADWEAR</font></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

live example: https://jsfiddle.net/1L30cvrp/

Comment: hmm - must be something funky on my side then - this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

not sure but you might try this:

```
onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';"
```

it's not clear...

Comment: here is an example of how it works - with dropdown content `<div class="dropdown"> <div style="height:51px;"onclick="return false;"> <button class="dropbtn">APPAREL</button> </div> <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=2&subcat=1">T-SHIRTS</‌​a>`

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
onclick="window.location.href = 'default.aspx?p=etc...."
```

Comment: same problem - wont go

Comment: do you have any other jQuery errors on the page that may stop the onclick from working. Can you get an alert to work onclick on the button.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <div style="height:51px;">
      <button  id="myButton" class="dropbtn"><font color="#FFFFFF">HEADWEAR</font></button>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
location.href = "http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx?p=viewcat&showpage=3";
}; 
</script>
```